# Timing body transmission in HTTP requests using restify/express

Tags: node.js, express, restify

A HTTP application is sending a large body in a specific POST method. I would like to measure the time taken in the server since the headers were received until the body was received. Is there a way I can assign events (data, end) to a route definition in restify or express? I wouldn't like to switch to node.js's raw HTTP server.

Answer (score 1):

Restify uses [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) to process file uploads. You can use the [bodyParser](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#Bundled-Plugins) plugin bundled with restify to listen to events on the multipart file handler. The `end` event can be logged to know when the file was completely received.

Use the restify server's pre() method to record when the request was received.

```
var restify = require('restify');
var server = restify.createServer();

server.post('/upload', function(req, res, next){
  res.send({upload: 'done'});
  next();
});

server.pre(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("Request received at: " + req._time);
  next();
});

server.use(restify.bodyParser({
  multipartFileHandler: function(part) {
    // Fired when the parser is done receiving the file
    part.on('end', function(data) {
      console.log('File parsing ended: ' + new Date().getTime());      
    });
  }
}));

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```